# JQuery callback on function

Tags: jquery

I have the following action:

```
   $('.sub_outworker').live('click', function() {

                var input = $(this);
                var current_div = input.parents('div.report');
                var current_div_id = current_div.attr('id');
                var replace_div = current_div.children('div').first();
                var submission = submit_form(input, replace_div);
                var i = 0;
}
```

The submit_form() function looks like this:

```
function submit_form(input, replace_div) {
            var form = input.parents('form');

            loading_gif(replace_div);

             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: 'ajax=true&' + form.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    get_json();

                    if(data == 'success') {
                        return 'success';
                    }
                    else {
                        return 'failed';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I want to check whether submission == failed and if it does run submit_form again (ie. give the function a second chance to work - mainly because it occasionally fails validation due to a mismatch in tokens).  I'm not sure how to go about this though!

Comment: You cannot return any value from the `success` callback.

Comment: `submit_form` does not return anything.

Comment: That probably explains why I couldn't get my attempts to work earlier!

Comment: Once the success callback has completed is it possible to return something, or do any subsequent actions also need to be placed in the callback?

Comment: @bland_dan unless you're using the deferred object API, subsequent actions ***always*** need to go in the callback.

Comment: Hm, what does `get_json()` do?

Comment: @MДΓΓ: Well, even deferred objects only accept callbacks. So you can say everything has to handled with callbacks if you deal with asynchronous code.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL, get_json() is used to reset the token within the form.  The token is unset when the form is processed, so get_json ensures that there is a valid token in the html form should the user re-submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to run it one more time, the easiest (and IMO cleanest) way might be to use [deferred objects *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function submit_form(input, replace_div) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var form = input.parents('form');

    loading_gif(replace_div);

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: 'ajax=true&' + form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            get_json();

            if(data == 'success') {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
        }
    });

    return deferred;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var request = submit_form(input, replace_div);
request.fail(function() {
    submit_form(input, replace_div);
}).done(function() {
   // request was successful, do something
});
```

Deferred objects provide great flexibility with asynchronous calls and let you easily decouple code. Of course if you want to see the repeated attempt to make the Ajax call as a "feature" of the `submit_form` function or if you want to repeat it more than once, then [@Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750475/218196) seems to be the better way.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be done in the `$.ajax()` callback.

```
$('.sub_outworker').live('click', function() {

    var input = $(this);
    var current_div = input.parents('div.report');
    var current_div_id = current_div.attr('id');
    var replace_div = current_div.children('div').first();
    submit_form(input, replace_div);
}

function submit_form(input, replace_div) {
    var form = input.parents('form');

    loading_gif(replace_div);

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: 'ajax=true&' + form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            get_json();

            if(data == 'success') {
                submit_form.failCount = 0;
            }
            else if (!submit_form.failCount) {
                submit_form.failCount++;
                submit_form(input, replace_div);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It could also be interesting to utilize deferred objects to be more flexible, but this is a simple solution which works. +1 :)

Comment: Looks like we posted similar answers. Only difference I can see is that I restructured slightly to avoid re-serialising the data on the form...

Comment: @bland: Ooook, with so much support ;) My original solution suggested to use the deferred object returned by `$.ajax` but that would only `fail` if the request itself fails, not when you just get a different value than `success`. You can still use your own deferred object though. See my updated answer.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL was a close run thing, have used Felix deferred object suggestion

Comment: @bland_dan no worries, I agree that his solution is cleaner for a one-off retry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? Note, I'm not 100% sure what you're expecting to get back from the server, or exactly how your page is structured.

```
function submit_form_ajax(serializedData, numAttempts) {

     numAttempts--;

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: 'ajax=true&' + serializedData,
        success: function(data) {
            get_json();

            if(data !== 'success') {
                if( numAttempts >= 1 ) {
                    submit_form_ajax(serializedData, numAttempts-1);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

function submit_form(input, replace_div) {
    var form = input.parents('form');

    loading_gif(replace_div);

    submit_form_ajax(form.serialize(), 2);
}
```